# javascript calling info

Tags: javascript

I created a facebook fanpage(iframe) application. I would like to fetch the addressbar information from the fanpage iframe.

I tried alert(top.location.href) from fanpage iframe application, but nothing happens.

If i use top.location.href = www.google.com then it works, but if I just use alert(top.location.href) nothing happens.

This must mean that it is writable but not readable.

How can I solve this?

Comment: **Please do not speak in bold**

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You can't access data from a different domain.  Trying to do so throws a "Permission Denied" error.  If `top.location.host != location.host`, you cannot access its data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with Chrome, [according to CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=511570).

Running this locally wont work either, have you tried on a webserver?